# Bootstrap Tags Input - how to prefill object values

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I'm using Bootstrap Tags Input in my form, initalized with following code:

```
$('#looking_for_job_titles').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'id',
    itemText: 'name'
});

// TypeAhead.js 
var job_scopes = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 100,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://www.domain.com/json.php?action=job_title&q=%QUERY'
    }
});

job_scopes.initialize();

$('#looking_for_job_titles').tagsinput('input').typeahead({
        itemValue: 'name'
    },
    {
        name: 'job_scope',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: job_scopes.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                'no results found',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function(data){
                return '<p>'+ data.industry +'> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong></p>';
            }
        },
        engine: Hogan
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
        this.tagsinput('add', datum);
    }, $('#looking_for_job_titles')));
```

This works fine, and returns comma separated list of ids, which I save into db.

My problem is how to prefill the object values back into the input field on page refresh? The object looks like:

```
[{"id":"80001","name":"Account Manager"},{"id":"80251","name":"Projektant"}]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone needing this:

```
$.each(obj, function(index, value) {
    $('#looking_for_job_titles').tagsinput('add', value);
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Check the document on Method [here](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#methods).

You can use:

```
$('input').tagsinput('add', 'some tag');
```

and

```
$('input').tagsinput('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be simple, fill `value=""` attribute of that input, but without javascript.
If you do this in the correct format `value="1,2,3"` it will work

Comment: Yup, but I need the id + value combo. See my solution at the bottom.

Comment: what if you store that value as json in input and use json_encode and decode it in backend?

Answer (score 0):

so it will be

```
value=" [{"id":"80001","name":"Account Manager"},{"id":"80251","name":"Projektant"}]"
```